# Install Retail Windows 7 Ultimate disk with Home Premium OEM CD Key

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have an OEM Windows 7 Home Premium cd key and a Windows 7 Ultimate Retail Install disk.  What procedure would I have to do to install home premium with my cd key?  Do I need to edit ei.cfg?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to either edit the `ei.cfg` and replace `Ultimate` with `HomePremium`, or delete the file entirely.

http://windows7center.com/news/how-to-install-any-version-or-sku-of-windows-7/ gives a more detailed step-by-step process of doing so:

1. Open the disk image in 7-Zip
2. Delete or edit `sources/ei.cfg`:

   - Delete to have the option select the SKU you want during install, **or**
   - Change the `EditionID` value to be the SKU that you want:

     - `Ultimate`
     - `Premium`
     - `HomePremium`
     - `HomeBasic`
     - `Starter`
3. Save the image and burn it to disk

Comment: When I delete the ei.cfg completely, does it default the channel to Retail or OEM?

Comment: I missed that portion of your question - deleting the file entirely will allow you to select the SKU (Starter, Basic, Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate), though nothing is mentioned about Retail or OEM - I'm under the impression that the only difference between Retail / OEM keys are that the OEM motherboards often have them embedded so no activation is needed at all, but the key is otherwise a valid key for windows. I know for XP, the keys you got with the OEM systems worked fine with retail install disks, and I'd expect Windows 7 to be the same.

Comment: The key didn't work, so I had to do a phone activation.

Comment: If a delete ei.cfg will I be able to activate Ultimate version with key from Home Premium?

Comment: The article you linked to has gone dead. Can you summarize the process?

Comment: @BrantBobby Included. The article itself is still available via [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100601072857/http://windows7center.com/news/how-to-install-any-version-or-sku-of-windows-7/)